# AngularJS controller - interacting with view elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After watching AngularJS best practices, they state that DOM manipulation should not be done in the controller, and I do buy that entirely.

So, lets say that I'm using Twitter bootstrap and displays a modal dialog there.
If I want to close this dialog from a function in my controller.

then I cant go about and do  $('#registerDialog').modal('hide'); since that is tying the controller to a DOM element.

What is the correct way to do this from within the controller?

Comment: do you have separate controller for dialog?

Comment: If so, you should be able to close the dialog with `dialog.close();`

Comment: No I don't have a separate controller, but even if I did, somewhere there needs to be a .modal('hide'); call done on the actual view element... or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you are missing. Let me get a link for you!

Comment: Dialog is just another view, so have another controller for that. 
Check this out: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog

Comment: especially this one: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog#dialogtemplateurl-controller

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses data binding between the *$scope* to the DOM to do these sort of things.
If you want to hide your popup when something happens, you should use the *ng-hide* directive on the root of your modal dialog, and bind it to a boolean value that exists on the scope.
First, if you want to set up this value on the scope, all you have to do in your controller:

```
$scope.isModalHidden = <true|false>
```

If this is something that happens as a result of an async operation (e.g. timeout / server response), you should wrap the previous statement, like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.isModalHidden = <true|false>
});
```

This will cause Angular to reevaluate *isModalHidden* even though it wasn't changed as a part of the "natural" flow of events.

After that is finished, all you have to do is bind it to the DOM, like so:

```
<div id="registerDialog" ng-hide="{isModalHidden}">...</div>
```

I hope this helps.